# How to build Sveltekit application

Tags: deployment, svelte, sveltekit

For a project I'm doing I'm trying out Sveltekit. I'm not really experienced in building and deploying applications. When using Angular, I was used to just running `ng build --prod` and place the output in the dist folder on a server. Now when I run `npm run build` with Sveltekit, the output does not contain an index.html.

What I expected was an output ready to be placed on a server using ftp. How do I go about this with Sveltekit?

Comment: You probably need to add an adapter: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#adapters . In your case it sounds like adapter-static is the right choice for you: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static

Comment: Alright! That did the trick. Thanks so much.

Answer (score -2):

You start an app like this:

```
npm init svelte@next my-app
cd my-app
npm install
npm run dev
```

and in pacage.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "svelte-kit dev",
    "build": "svelte-kit build"
}
```

Normally it has to work.